# How this javascript code is wroking?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how this JavaScript code is finding these text strings, ("aaa", "bbb", and "ccc") on my page.

Each is separated in the code.

Thank You

Here is the code:

```
    function ae(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof oldonload != 'function') {
      window.onload = func;
    } else {
      window.onload = function () {
        oldonload();
        func();
      }
    }
  }
  function qw(e, t, n) {
    if (e && "undefined" != typeof t)for (var r = "string" == typeof e ? new RegExp(e, "g") : e, a = (n || document.body).childNodes, d = a.length, i = "html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe"; d--;) {
      var o = a[d];
      if (1 === o.nodeType && -1 === (i + ",").indexOf(o.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ",") && arguments.callee(e, t, o), 3 === o.nodeType && r.test(o.data)) {
        var l = o.parentNode, c = function () {
          var e = o.data.replace(r, t), n = document.createElement("div"), a = document.createDocumentFragment();
          for (n.innerHTML = e; n.firstChild;)a.appendChild(n.firstChild);
          return a
        }();
        l.insertBefore(c, o), l.removeChild(o)
      }
    }
  }
  ae(fg);
  function fg() {
    qw('aaa', 'a');
    qw('bbb', 'b');
    qw('ccc', 'c');
  }``
```

Comment: You may want to add more details about the code

Comment: The answer to your question requires a lot of mind-power, but does not give any value to the community... 
so you are in risk to be a victim of a negative voting shit-storm, just because this kind of questions are not welcome here.

Comment: Even if this code is genius, you should not program like that. The reason ist, that this style of coding is impossible to debug.

Comment: @Steffomio its obvious that this a part of some minimized code, this guy has no clue..

Comment: @webdeb Thats exactly the reason why I've written what i've written ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok, so let's break it down as best we can.

```
// -------------------------
// add an additional step (function) to the onload handler.
// -------------------------
function ae(func) {
    // -------------------------
    // save the current onload handler to a variable
    // -------------------------
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    // -------------------------

    // -------------------------
    // meld the current onload and the new "func" together.
    // -------------------------
    if (typeof oldonload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
      window.onload = function () {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
    // -------------------------
}
// -------------------------
```

The job of ae() is to "add" its parameter (a function) to the window onload handler.

```
// -------------------------
// call qw() a few times
// -------------------------
function fg() {
    qw('a', 'a');
    qw('b', 'b');
    qw('ccc', 'c');
}
// -------------------------
```

fg() simply calls qw() a few times...

```
// -------------------------
// add a function "fg" to the onload handler
// -------------------------
ae(fg);
// -------------------------
```

At this point what we have is the function fg() will be added to the windows onload() thanks to the work of ae().  Ultimately, onload, qw() will be executed three times (in addition to any other work already defined for the onload...

This leaves us with qw() which I have expanded and restructured for clarity...

```
// -------------------------------
// "e" regex pattern
// "t" replacement string
// "n" root node
// -------------------------------
// under "n" defaulting to <body /> recursively find text nodes
// and apply the regex pattern "e" to search and place with "t"
// -------------------------------
function qw(e, t, n) {
    // -------------------------------
    // if the parameters are not good, abort
    // -------------------------------
    if (!e || "undefined" === typeof t) { return; }
    // -------------------------------

    // -------------------------------
    // "a" holds child nodes of <body />
    // unless we passing in a new parent as parameter "n"
    // -------------------------------
    var a = (n || document.body).childNodes;
    // -------------------------------

    // -------------------------------
    // d indicates how many nodes we found
    // -------------------------------
    var d = a.length;
    // -------------------------------

    // -------------------------------
    // "i" holds a list of tags that we will not process as we will discover later
    // -------------------------------
    var i = "html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe";
    // -------------------------------

    // -------------------------------
    // if "e" is a string "r" shall hold a regex based on "e"
    // otherwise "r" shall hold "e"
    // -------------------------------
    var r = (("string" == typeof e) ? new RegExp(e, "g") : e);
    // -------------------------------

    // -------------------------------
    // do until d === 0
    // i.e. do once for each child node identified above...
    // -------------------------------
    for (; d--; ) {
        // -------------------------------
        // o shall be the "current" child node
        // -------------------------------
        var o = a[d];
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // cnd1 shall indicate if "o" is an "Element" (div, p, ...)
        // -------------------------------
        var cnd1 = (1 === o.nodeType);
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // cnd2 shall indicate if "o" is not in the list "i"
        // -------------------------------
        var cnd2 = (-1 === (i + ",").indexOf(o.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ","));
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // The comma operator is intentionally messing with us!
        // if "o" is an Element but not a "bad" one recurse
        // -------------------------------
        if (cnd1 && cnd2) { arguments.callee(e, t, o); }
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // "cnd3" shall indicate if "o" is actual text
        // -------------------------------
        var cnd3 = (3 === o.nodeType);
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // "cnd4" shall indicate if "o" matches our regex "r"
        // -------------------------------
        var cnd4 = (r.test(o.data));
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // if "o" is not the text part of a node or if it is but not a hit then move on
        // -------------------------------
        if (!cnd3 || !cnd4) { continue; )
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // Get the parent of this text (the prior "o")
        // -------------------------------
        var l = o.parentNode;
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // "c" will be a collection of text nodes (single) the result of a search and replace based on the initial parameters
        // -------------------------------
        var c = function () {
            // -------------------------------
            // NOTE: after this point local "e" scopes parameter "e"
            // in this context "e" is now the results of our search and replace
            // -------------------------------
            var e = o.data.replace(r, t);
            // -------------------------------

            // -------------------------------
            // create a template div to hold our new text "e"
            // in turn this will allow us to essentially convert "e" to a node
            // -------------------------------
            var n = document.createElement("div");
            n.innerHTML = e;
            // -------------------------------

            // -------------------------------
            // "a" shall be a container for new child nodes
            // -------------------------------
            var a = document.createDocumentFragment();
            // -------------------------------

            // -------------------------------
            // note sure if there are ever any more than 1 but this
            // moves all the children of "n" to be children of "a"
            // -------------------------------
            for (; n.firstChild; ) { a.appendChild( n.firstChild ); }
            // -------------------------------

            // -------------------------------
            // return our new node container with the results of the search and replace
            // -------------------------------
            return a
            // -------------------------------
        }();
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // add the results node "c" to the parent just prior to the current "o"
        // -------------------------------
        l.insertBefore(c, o);
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // now remove from the parent the current "o"
        // -------------------------------
        l.removeChild(o)
        // -------------------------------

        // -------------------------------
        // effectively we have replaced "o" with "c"
        // -------------------------------
    }
}
// -------------------------------
```